# How to do an edge counter/clock detector for a Raspberry PI(as linux kernel driver)?

Tags: linux-kernel, raspberry-pi, linux-device-driver, gpio, edge-detection

Hej

I connected to one of my raspberry pi pins to a voltage controlled oscillator. A change of one of the oscillator capacity changes the output frequency. My question is how to realize the frequency detection?

There some constraints:

1st.) I like to keep the cpu consumption low.

2nd.) I like to have a file based interface, which my user space app can query for the actual frequency.

I was checking the Linux GPIO driver. But I see no possibility to configure a pin as an edge counter.

The raspberry [pi soc data sheet](https://www.raspberrypi.org/app/uploads/2012/02/BCM2835-ARM-Peripherals.pdf) describes at page 86 (chapter "6 General Purpose I/O (GPIO)")registers to configure a gpio to detect edges.

Any ideas how to configure these registers in a kernel character device driver?

Comment: Using a GPIO pin to "count" edges would be CPU intensive and constrain the maximum frequency that can be reported.  Instead a *timer counter* peripheral (in capture mode) is typically employed to perform event counting and frequency measurement.  However the Broadcom SoC datasheet indicates that there is no such *timer counter* peripheral for the RPI.  See chapter 54 of this [Microchip SoC datasheet](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/DS60001476B.pdf) for an example of a timer counter peripheral .

Comment: the counter is generating an interrupt(see figure 6-1). Seems that I need to catch this interrupt signal

Comment: What counter are you referring to?

Comment: @counter I am refering to a classical capture/compare unit. It seems that there is not such unit available at the SOC (https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/9787/pwm-input-in-raspberry-pi). Thats why I want to configure the GPIO generating an interrup at the falling edge. The interrupthandler is incrementing an own "register"=fixed memory. The kernel driver reads the value in that memory after an interval. the frequency is calculated after: counted edges/time in seconds

Comment: *"I want to configure the GPIO ..."* -- Read the first sentence of my first comment above.  Using the CPU to process each event/edge is only suitable/reliable for low-frequency sources (maybe up to a few kHz).